# MongooseJS separate user and profile schemas

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm trying to create 2 mongoose schemas, one for user, mainly used for authentication, and another for the user profile, where it will have the user's profile image, bio...etc

How can I create a profile document automatically, when creating a user document using mongoose hooks, and how do I create a (one-to-one) relationship between both schemas ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a model file as per the following code snip & update params as per your requirements

User.model.js

```
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Profile = new Schema({
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  bio: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

let User = new Schema({
    email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
  profile: Profile,
}, {timestamp: true});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```